# CSS align textfield input

Tags: html, css

I want to align my textfield input. Currently it looks like this:

http://2.imgland.net/Fk7zSx.png

I can't find a way to center it.

Here's my login css:

```
.login{
background:url(../images/footer.png) bottom left repeat-x;
width:330px;
text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
font-family:'Oswald', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
color:#fff;
font-size:13px;
font-weight:700;
text-transform:uppercase;
padding:0px 0px 16px 0px;
margin:0px 0px 10px 1px;
float:left;
vertical-align:top;
```

}

also, my textfields input and textarea css:

```
  /* Forms */

textarea, input {
    color: #666;
    padding: 5px;
    border: solid 1px #E5E5E5;
    background: url(../images/textfield.png) 0 0 repeat-x white;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
    width:220px;
}
textarea:focus, input:focus {
    outline:none;
}
textarea:hover, input:hover, textarea:active, input:active {
    border:1px solid #2ac0ff;
    transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
textarea {
    background: url(../images/textarea.png) 0 0 repeat-x white;
    height:152px;
}
```

So, I can't find a way to center it. Also, if it's needed, here's my login form in html:

```
<div class="login">
<div class="header">Login / Register</div>
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
        <li>
            Username: <br>
            <input type="text" name="username">
        </li>
        <li>
            Password: <br>
            <input type="password" name="password">
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" value="Log in">
        </li>
        <?php
            /* Form file */
            Token::create();
        ?>

    <center>    <h3><a href="register.php">New account</a></h3>
    <font size="1">- Lost <a href="recovery.php?mode=username">username</a> or <a href="recovery.php?mode=password">password</a>?</font></center>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Is there anyway to align it? I tried several things, but none of them really worked.

Comment: align relative to what? center of form? could you elaborate?

Comment: a jsFiddle -->  http://jsfiddle.net/ would be nice :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add css `text-align: center;` to class login check this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paYUg/)**

Comment: thanks it worked, just another question, how could I make the form just a bit to right (without the centering)?

Comment: whole form? if yes then add some margin left to it.

Answer (score 0):

in style sheet just use (clear: both;) for div u want to align center.
Then define (align:center;)